# Why is the `of` operand not needed when using dd with a pipe?

Tags: shell, dd

I've come across this piece of code:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda | ssh username@10.1.1.5 \ "cat > /media/disk1/sda-image.img"
```

Shouldn't there be an `of` operand somewhere in this code? Also, what is the purpose of the `\`?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many old Unix utilities, `dd` (actually older than Unix) is designed so it can be combined with other commands using pipes. The `of` argument is only required if you want its output to be written to a file; otherwise the default behaviour of `dd` is to write the data to `stdout`. In this case, the output from the `dd` command is piped using `ssh` to the `cat` command running on a remote host.

The `\` doesn't do anything when the complete command is contained in one line. It's usually used in shell scripts immediately before a line break to inform the shell that the rest of the command continues on the following line.